# How should I plant Calathea Medallion seeds?

Tags: flowers, seeds, germination

I have a nice Calathea Medallion in my living room, and it has flowered, and now I'd like to try and plant the seeds. However the flower is a little... funny looking, so to speak, and I wouldn't know what part to plant and under what conditions. So please, how to plant Calathea Medallion seeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only plant seeds if the flowers produce seeds or seed pods, and they'll only do that if they're pollinated by bees or other insects, and that's unlikely to happen indoors. If the flowers just die off and don't produce any kind of seed or seed capsule, then obviously you won't have any seeds to plant. You could try division, to increase your stock, but it's not easy to do with these particular plants, and there's a high risk of losing the plant altogether.

Comment: Right. I had biology, how did I not think of that. There's zero chance of the plant being pollinated. I have only one and I live in the middle of a city.

Comment: @Jasper Kennis: You can buy seeds for this online if you really want to try and grow them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Only a few *Calathea* species are fertile, and I don't think 'Medallion' is one of them. Of course, if you have a seed capsule, not only a funny flower, post a picture of it. We'll be able to tell which part to plant better. Professionals use cuttings, not seeds, to multiply their stock. This is a very involved process, and I wouldn't recommend you try it until you have a lot more experience in that field.

I'm thinking the best route will be to leave the plant alone. You can easily but a new plant if you want more.

Comment: Thanks. I won't kill the plant;) I'm mostly interested in the duplication, but I will get another plant that's easier to divide.